# grid: How to rotate y-axis labels properly?

Tags: r

How can I rotate the labels of the y-axis (created with `grid.yaxis()`) in the following grid plot properly? The idea commented out can be found in Paul Murrell's book, but for some reason it fails. A version which works is to use `grid.edit("yaxis1", edits=gEdit("labels", rot=90))` as given below, but then the labels are not properly centered at the ticks anymore...

```
require(grid)

X <- matrix(rexp(2000), ncol=2)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(4,4,4,4)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(X[,1], X[,2]))
grid.points(X[,1], X[,2], pch=1)
grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis(name="yaxis1")
grid.edit("yaxis1", edits=gEdit("labels", rot=90))
#grid.edit("yaxis1::labels", rot=90) # => fails with "Error in editDLfromGPat(hgPath, specs, strict, grep, global, redraw) : 'gPath' (yaxis1::labels) not found"
upViewport()
```

Comment: You should re-run with your now-edited code. It works without complaint on my box with R-14.2 to the current R-devel. Does it still give you the error pasted into your question?

Comment: Thanks for helping, Josh. The error is just one thing (comment this line in and comment out the line `grid.edit("yaxis1", edits=gEdit("labels", rot=90))' to see that the error appears. I was more wondering about the horizontal adjustment of the labels (is there some `hadj`?), since it looks ugly at the moment. Something I'm also wondering is: `grid.yaxis(edits=gEdit("labels", rot=90))` does not work although first using `grid.yaxis(name="yaxis1")` and then addressing this name in `grid.edit` does work (as you see in the example). That seems strange (but I'm totally new to `grid`...)

Comment: `grid.edit("yaxis1", edits=gEdit("labels", rot=90, hjust=0.5))` does the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot, baptiste, that solved it. Just out of interest: Do you know why specifying the very same `edits` (so `edits=gEdit(...)`) in `grid.yaxis` directly fails? Well, to be more precise, I receive the `Warning message: In editGrob(list(at = NULL, label = TRUE, main = TRUE, edits = list( : 'gPath' (labels) not found`

If that worked one could omit the extra line with the call of `grid.edit`.